# Parse JSON with duplicate key:value pairs to dataframe

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup

I'm working with the Eventful API, which returns a JSON with a bunch of keys and values about events. A simplified version of the JSON (with key:value pairs I don't use removed) is below:

```
{'events': {'event': [{'all_day': '0',
    'calendar_count': None,
    'calendars': None,
    'categories': {'category': [
    {'id': 'books', 'name': 'Literary &amp; Books'},
    {'id': 'attractions', 'name': 'Museums &amp; Attractions'},
    {'id': 'community', 'name': 'Neighborhood'}]},
    'title': 'Totally Random Book Club @ Lionel Bowen Library'},
{'all_day': '0',
    'calendar_count': None,
    'calendars': None,
    'categories': {'category': [
    {'id': 'books', 'name': 'Literary &amp; Books'},
    {'id': 'business', 'name': 'business'}]},
    'title': 'ABCs of Business Management'}
                         ]
               }
    }
```

So each 'title' can correspond to multiple 'id' key:values pairs. What I'd like to do is be able to put this info into a dataframe like below (doesn't have to be exactly like below, just need a way to group a title to multiple 'ids'):

[image]

I attempted this using the code below, the problem being that the shape of the passed values aren't equal:

```
event_json_title = [title['title'] for title in event_json_read['events']['event']]
event_json_id = [name['id'] for cat in event_json_read['events']['event'] for name in cat['categories']['category']]
df = pd.DataFrame({'title':event_json_title},{'id':event_json_id})
```

I suspect the answer lies in some appending...I'm just not sure how to do this in a manner that can group each 'id' to the 'title'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that the response variable is the response of the API that you call:

```
temp = list()    
for event in response['events']['event']:
  for category in event['categories']['category']:
    category['title'] = event['title'] 
    temp.append(category)
df = pd.DataFrame(temp).groupby('title').apply(lambda x: ", ".join(x['id']))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach.

**Ex:**

```
event_json_title = [{"title": title['title'], "id": ",".join([i["id"] for i in title['categories']['category']])} for title in event_json_read['events']['event']]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(event_json_title)
print(df["title"])
print "---"
print(df["id"])
```

**Output:**

```
0    Totally Random Book Club @ Lionel Bowen Library
1                        ABCs of Business Management
Name: title, dtype: object
---
0    books,attractions,community
1                 books,business
Name: id, dtype: object
```